# Long exact sequence in homology of a $3$-manifold with nonconnected boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology, group-homomorphism, exact-sequence

Let $M^3$ be a compact, connected and orientable smooth manifold with boundary $\partial M$. Suppose $\partial M$ consists of two connected components: $\partial_1 M$ and $\partial_2 M$.

The long exact sequence in homology (with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients) of the pair $(M, \partial M)$ is:

$$ 0 \to H_3(M, \partial M) \cong \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{f}{\to} H_2(\partial M) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2 \stackrel{g}{\to} H_2(M) \stackrel{h}{\to} H_2(M, \partial M) \stackrel{\partial}{\to} H_1(\partial M) \to \cdots$$

**Can we identify the map $f$ and extract information about $g$, $h$ and $\partial$?**

**My thoughts:** if $\partial M$ were connected, then $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ would be an isomorphism. In particular, $\partial : H_2(M, \partial M) \to H_1(\partial M)$ is injective if and only if $H_2(M) = 0$.

Comment: The construction of a LES for pairs is explained in pretty much every Algebraic Topology textbook. Did you try to follow this description? This will tell you what these maps are (the connecting homomorphisms $f$ and $\partial$ will be tiny bit more complicated than $g$ and $h$). For instance, the image of $f$ will be a diagonal subgroup in $Z^2$.

Comment: $f$ takes the the fundamental class of $M$ to the sum of a possible fundamental class for either component. The other maps are best understood in the usual way for this LES.